# Disabling a radiobutton if i am logged in as a standard user

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I have a radio button group and I have 3 radio buttons in it. I want to disable a radio button, however I want this thing to be done as follows:

> When I logged in as an admin the radio button must not be disabled and 
>   if i am logged in as a standard user the UI should not display the radio button.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Privileged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370852%28v=vs.85%29) property in a [Condition](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_condition.htm) element.